# div jumps when it has content

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

When a div in my project has content in it, it jumps down. Depending on the content it moves around. I do not want the "dashboard-tile" div to move because of its content. How do I do that?
I think the problem is in the html and css below, did I forget something or do something wrong here? It happens in both google chrome and internet explorer. When all the divs have the same content it also works the way I want. (see screenshot 2)
For me it's hard to solve this problem, as I don't exactly know where the problem is. It also makes it hard for me to find a solution on the internet.

Html:

```
<div class="meters">
    <div class="dashboard-tile">other content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile">content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile">content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
</div>
```

Css:

```
.meters {
    text-align: justify;
}

.dashboard-tile {
    background-color: rgb(230,240,230);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 265px;
    width: 186px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

[**screenshot 1**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ukndxpxrjwwcf2/Screenshot%20%2862%29.png?dl=0) (problem)

[**screenshot 2**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0hpuds2vwil535/Screenshot%20%2863%29.png?dl=0) (preferred result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `vertical-align: top` on your divs to make sure they are all aligned the same way:

```
.dashboard-tile {
    background-color: rgb(230,240,230);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 265px;
    width: 186px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmk4eLnu/)

Comment: What is the difference between overflow:hidden and vertical-align:top? It seems like it both solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align:top;` as the default is `baseline` for inline-block elements

```
   .dashboard-tile {
    background-color: rgb(230,240,230);
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 7px;
    height: 265px;
    width: 186px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure who was the first with this solution, you or gaynorvader. What is the difference between overflow:hidden and vertical-align:top? It seems like it both solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to contain the contents within `.dashboard-tile` using [block formatting context](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/)

```
.dashboard-tile {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between overflow:hidden and vertical-align:top? It seems like it both solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go FLEXBOX, make **.meters** a flexbox container that controls the **.dashboard-tile**'s

Check the snippet (full screen!) for comments:

```css
.meters {
    display: flex;       /* add, make it a flexbox container */
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* add, default = row nowrap */
    justify-content: space-between; /* default = flex-start */

    /* text-align: justify; remove */
}

.dashboard-tile { 
    background-color: rgb(230,240,230);
    /* display: inline-block; remove */
    padding: 7px;
    height: 265px;
    width: 186px;
    /* position: relative; remove
    top: 0px;              remove
    left: 0px;             remove */
    margin-bottom: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="meters">
    <div class="dashboard-tile">other content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile">content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile">content</div>
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
    <div class="dashboard-tile"></div><!--no content-->
</div>
```

Comment: This made all the dashboard tiles go above eachother and some divs inside the dashboards tiles got messed up.

Comment: Checked snippet and clean webpage - IE11, Chrome, Firefox Standard and Developer Ed. give the same (your preferred) result. Maybe IE Edge has a different opinion on Flexbox? Anyway, gaynorvader's code seems to work for you, go with that and save Flex'ing for darker days...